# Is there a way to let classes inherit the documentation of their superclass with sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Suppose I have a class

```
class A(object):
  def myfunction():
    """A."""
    pass
```

and a subclass

```
class B(A):
  def myfunction():
    pass
```

is it possible to inherit the API doc of B.myfunction from A.myfunction with sphinx? The documentation for B.myfunction should be "A." as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, you can set an object's documentation by assigning to its "docstring" `__doc__` after it is created. The cleanest way to do this is by using a decorator that copies the docstring of the parent class. You can even provide an additional docstring for `B.myfunction`, and append it to the documentation of `A.myfunction` (since you are presumably specializing it). Using the following decorator (adapted from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218693/699305) to a similar question), you can copy the docstring of the overridden function like this:

```
def copydoc(fromfunc, sep="\n"):
    """
    Decorator: Copy the docstring of `fromfunc`
    """
    def _decorator(func):
        sourcedoc = fromfunc.__doc__
        if func.__doc__ == None:
            func.__doc__ = sourcedoc
        else:
            func.__doc__ = sep.join([sourcedoc, func.__doc__])
        return func
    return _decorator

class A(object):
  def myfunction():
    """Documentation for A."""
    pass

class B(A):
  @copydoc(A.myfunction)
  def myfunction():
    """Extra details for B."""
    pass
```

Result:

```
>>> help(B.myfunction)
Help on method myfunction in module __main__:

myfunction() unbound __main__.B method
    Documentation for A.
    Extra details for B.
```

This needs to explicitly say where you're copying the docstring from: `@copydoc(A.myfunction)`. It is arguably more flexible than a fully automatic solution, since you can choose where to copy from.

Based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306130/699305), I conclude that a clean, fully automatic solution is not possible: "Functions only become methods at runtime", says [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307263/699305) so the decorator has no way to look up the parent class name in the function object. The best you could do is a decorator `@copydoc(A)`. That's very easy, but then you might as well add the source method's name and retain the flexibility. (If you don't agree, comment and I'll provide the code).

Comment: Very good answer. It's a little bit strange that such a simple thing is not possible in python because of its flexibility. :D

Comment: I have implemented a more powerful version of this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000179/sphinx-insert-argument-documentation-from-parent-method/60012943#60012943