# Python-Sphinx: "inherit" method documentation from superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx, docstring

**Edit:**
As of now (Sphinx 1.4.9) there seems to be no way to tell Sphinx to do what I want (see [issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3140) on GitHub). The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613306/5682996) from Brecht Machiels solves the problem in an other way, until Sphinx might be able to do so one day.

**Description:**
I am trying to document a Python project with sphinx-apidoc. The Sphinx config is almost default, I just included `'sphinx.ext.autodoc'`.

It works in general, but derived classes do not inherit method documentation of their superclasses as I would expect it.

**Example:**
Consider a very minimalistic Python package called `project`. Aside an empty `__init__.py` it only consists of one file (`base.py`, see below)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import abc


class Superclass(object):
    """The one to rule them all"""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def give(self, ring):
        """Give out a ring"""
        pass


class Derived(Superclass):
    """Somebody has to do the work"""

    def give(self, ring):
        print("I pass the ring {} to you".format(ring))
```

Running sphinx-apidoc (`sphinx-apidoc -o apidoc project -f`) generates the following files:

- `apidoc/modules.rst`

  ```
  project
  =======

  .. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 4

     project
  ```
- `apidoc/project.rst`

  ```
  project package
  ===============

  Submodules
  ----------

  project.base module
  -------------------

  .. automodule:: project.base
      :members:
      :undoc-members:
      :show-inheritance:


  Module contents
  ---------------

  .. automodule:: project
      :members:
      :undoc-members:
      :show-inheritance:
  ```

Including `apidoc/modules.rst` in the default `index.rst` followed by `make html` generates a basic html documentation for both classes and their methods. Unfortunately, the docstring of `Derived.give` is empty.

**Question:** 
Is there a way to tell Sphinx to take the parent's method documentation without decorator magic as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741998/is-there-a-way-to-let-classes-inherit-the-documentation-of-their-superclass-with) SO post for every single method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manage docstrings automatically by employing a metaclass for the abstract base class. The following is a very basic implementation of such a metaclass. It needs to be extended to properly handle multiple base classes and corner cases.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import abc


class SuperclassMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, classname, bases, cls_dict):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, classname, bases, cls_dict)
        for name, member in cls_dict.items():
            if not getattr(member, '__doc__'):
                member.__doc__ = getattr(bases[-1], name).__doc__
        return cls


class Superclass(object, metaclass=SuperclassMeta):
    """The one to rule them all"""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def give(self, ring):
        """Give out a ring"""
        pass


class Derived(Superclass):
    """Somebody has to do the work"""

    def give(self, ring):
        print("I pass the ring {} to you".format(ring))
```

This is even a better solution than having Sphinx do this, because this will also work when calling `help()` on the derived classes.

Comment: Not quite the solution I hoped for, but it works like a charm for my purpose :-)

Comment: I have extended this solution to be more flexible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000179/sphinx-insert-argument-documentation-from-parent-method/60012943#60012943

Comment: The solution gives error when parent's methods don't have ``__doc__``.  It also happens when child has class attributes while parent doesn't. Inserting ``try`` and ``except AttributeError: pass`` solves it.