# Sphinx - insert argument documentation from parent method

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have some classes that inherit from each other. All classes contain the same method (let us call it `mymethod`), whereby the children overwrite the base class method. I want to generate a documentation for `mymethod` in all classes using [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/index.html).

Suppose `mymethod` takes an argument `myargument`. This argument has the same type and meaning for both the base method as well as the inherited method. To minimize redundancies, I would like to write the documentation for `myargument` only for the base class and **insert** the documentation in the child method's documentation. That is, I do not want to only put a simple reference to the base class but rather dynamically insert the text when I generate the documentation.

Can this be done? How?

Below please find some code illustrating the problem.

```
class BaseClass
    def mymethod(myargument):
        """This does something

        Params
        ------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument

        """
        [...]


class MyClass1(BaseClass):
    def mymethod(myargument):
        """This does something

        Params
        ------
        [here I would like to insert in the description of ``myargument`` from ``BaseClass.mymethod``]
        """

        BaseClass.mymethod(myargument)
        [...]

class MyClass2(BaseClass):
    def mymethod(myargument, argument2):
        """This does something

        Params
        ------
        [here I would like to insert in the description of ``myargument`` in ``BaseClass.mymethod``]
        argument2 : int
            Description of the additional argument

        """

        BaseClass.mymethod(argument)
        [...]
```

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40508492/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13741998/407651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not ideal, but maybe you could use a decorator to extend the docstring. For example:

```
class extend_docstring:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.doc = method.__doc__

    def __call__(self, function):
        if self.doc is not None:
            doc = function.__doc__
            function.__doc__ = self.doc
            if doc is not None:
                function.__doc__ += doc
        return function


class BaseClass:
    def mymethod(myargument):
        """This does something

        Params
        ------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument
        """
        [...]


class MyClass1(BaseClass):
    @extend_docstring(BaseClass.mymethod)
    def mymethod(myargument):
        BaseClass.mymethod(myargument)
        [...]

class MyClass2(BaseClass):
    @extend_docstring(MyClass1.mymethod)
    def mymethod(myargument, argument2):
        """argument2 : int
            Description of the additional argument
        """

        BaseClass.mymethod(argument)
        [...]


print('---BaseClass.mymethod---')
print(BaseClass.mymethod.__doc__)
print('---MyClass1.mymethod---')
print(MyClass1.mymethod.__doc__)
print('---MyClass2.mymethod---')
print(MyClass2.mymethod.__doc__)
```

Result:

```
---BaseClass.mymethod---
This does something

        Params
        ------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument

---MyClass1.mymethod---
This does something

        Params
        ------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument

---MyClass2.mymethod---
This does something

        Params
        ------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument
        argument2 : int
            Description of the additional argument
```

The override method could be resolved dynamically if you make the decorator a descriptor and search for it into `__get__` but that means the decorator is no longer stackable as it doesn't return the real function.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I have created a python package based on the code in this answer (with small modifications and improvements). The package can be installed via `pip install vemomoto_core_tools`; basic documentation can be found [here](https://vemomoto.github.io/vemomoto_core/tools/vemomoto_core.tools.doc_utils.html).

---

Based on the answer by @JordanBrière and the answers from [“inherit” method documentation from superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40508492/407651) and [Is there a way to let classes inherit the documentation of their superclass with sphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13741998/407651), I came up with a more sophisticated tool that does all the things I want.

In particular:

- Documentation of single arguments (numpy format) is taken from the superclass if not provided for the child.

  - You may add a new description of the method and renew the documentation of arguments to your liking, but undocumented arguments will be do documented from the super class.
- Documentation can be replaced, inserted, added, or ignored

  - The particular procedure can be controlled by adding a marker string to the beginning of the header, footer, type, or argument description
  - Description starting with `#` will be overwritten by the superclass
  - Description starting with `<!` will be put before the description from the super class
  - Description starting with `!>` will be put behind the description from the super class
  - Description without starting marker will replace the description from the super class
- Super classes can have documentation that is not carried over to the children

  - Lines after a line starting with `~+~` will be ignored by inheriting functions
- The tool is applicable to both entire classes (via metaclasses) and single methods (via decorators). The two can be combined.
- Via the decorator, multiple methods can be screened for suitable parameter definitions.

  - This is useful if the methods of concern bundles many other methods

The code is at the bottom of this answer.

**Usage (1):**

```
class BaseClass(metaclass=DocMetaSuperclass)
    def mymethod(myargument):
        """This does something

        ~+~

        This text will not be seen by the inheriting classes

        Parameters
        ----------
        myargument : int
            Description of the argument

        """
        [...]

    @add_doc(mymethod)
    def mymethod2(myargument, otherArgument):
        """>!This description is added to the description of mymethod
        (ignoring the section below ``~+~``)

        Parameters
        ----------
        otherArgument : int
            Description of the other argument
        [here the description of ``myargument`` will be inserted from mymethod]

        """
        BaseClass.mymethod(myargument)
        [...]


class MyClass1(BaseClass):
    def mymethod2(myargument):
        """This overwirtes the description of ``BaseClass.mymethod``

        [here the description of ``myargument`` from BaseClass.mymethod2 is inserted
         (which in turn comes from BaseClass.mymethod); otherArgument is ignored]
        """

        BaseClass.mymethod(myargument)
        [...]

class MyClass2(BaseClass):
    def mymethod2(myargument, otherArgument):
        """#This description will be overwritten

        Parameters
        ----------
        myargument : string <- this changes the type description only
        otherArgument [here the type description from BaseClass will be inserted]
            <! This text will be put before the argument description from BaseClass
        """

        BaseClass.mymethod2(myargument, otherArgument)
        [...]
```

**Usage (2):**

```
def method1(arg1):
    """This does something

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg1 : type
        Description

    """

def method2(arg2):
    """This does something

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg2 : type
        Description

    """

def method3(arg3):
    """This does something

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg3 : type
        Description

    """

@add_doc(method1, method2, method3)
def bundle_method(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    """This does something

    [here the parameter descriptions from the other 
     methods will be inserted]

    """
```

**The code:**

```
import inspect
import re 

IGNORE_STR = "#"
PRIVATE_STR = "~+~"
INSERT_STR = "<!"
APPEND_STR = ">!"

def should_ignore(string):
    return not string or not string.strip() or string.lstrip().startswith(IGNORE_STR)
def should_insert(string):
    return string.lstrip().startswith(INSERT_STR)
def should_append(string):
    return string.lstrip().startswith(APPEND_STR)

class DocMetaSuperclass(type):
    def __new__(mcls, classname, bases, cls_dict):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, classname, bases, cls_dict)
        if bases:
            for name, member in cls_dict.items():
                for base in bases:
                    if hasattr(base, name):
                        add_parent_doc(member, getattr(bases[-1], name))
                        break
        return cls

def add_doc(*fromfuncs):
    """
    Decorator: Copy the docstring of `fromfunc`
    """
    def _decorator(func):
        for fromfunc in fromfuncs:
            add_parent_doc(func, fromfunc)
        return func
    return _decorator


def strip_private(string:str):
    if PRIVATE_STR not in string:
        return string
    result = ""
    for line in string.splitlines(True):
        if line.strip()[:len(PRIVATE_STR)] == PRIVATE_STR:
            return result
        result += line
    return result

def merge(child_str, parent_str, indent_diff=0, joinstr="\n"):
    parent_str = adjust_indent(parent_str, indent_diff)
    if should_ignore(child_str):
        return parent_str
    if should_append(child_str):
        return joinstr.join([parent_str, re.sub(APPEND_STR, "", child_str, count=1)])
    if should_insert(child_str):
        return joinstr.join([re.sub(INSERT_STR, "", child_str, count=1), parent_str])
    return child_str

def add_parent_doc(child, parent):

    if type(parent) == str:
        doc_parent = parent
    else:
        doc_parent = parent.__doc__

    if not doc_parent:
        return

    doc_child = child.__doc__ if child.__doc__ else ""
    if not callable(child) or not (callable(parent) or type(parent) == str):
        indent_child = get_indent_multi(doc_child)
        indent_parent = get_indent_multi(doc_parent)
        ind_diff = indent_child - indent_parent if doc_child else 0

        try:
            child.__doc__ = merge(doc_child, strip_private(doc_parent), ind_diff)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return

    vars_parent, header_parent, footer_parent, indent_parent = split_variables_numpy(doc_parent, True)
    vars_child, header_child, footer_child, indent_child = split_variables_numpy(doc_child)


    if doc_child:
        ind_diff = indent_child - indent_parent 
    else: 
        ind_diff = 0
        indent_child = indent_parent


    header = merge(header_child, header_parent, ind_diff)
    footer = merge(footer_child, footer_parent, ind_diff)

    variables = inspect.getfullargspec(child)[0]

    varStr = ""

    for var in variables:
        child_var_type, child_var_descr = vars_child.get(var, [None, None]) 
        parent_var_type, parent_var_descr = vars_parent.get(var, ["", ""]) 
        var_type = merge(child_var_type, parent_var_type, ind_diff, joinstr=" ")
        var_descr = merge(child_var_descr, parent_var_descr, ind_diff)
        if bool(var_type) and bool(var_descr):
            varStr += "".join([adjust_indent(" ".join([var, var_type]), 
                                               indent_child), 
                                 var_descr])

    if varStr.strip():
        varStr = "\n".join([adjust_indent("\nParameters\n----------", 
                                          indent_child), varStr])

    child.__doc__ = "\n".join([header, varStr, footer])

def adjust_indent(string:str, difference:int) -> str:    
    if not string:
        if difference > 0:
            return " " * difference
        else:
            return ""
    if not difference:
        return string
    if difference > 0:
        diff = " " * difference
        return "".join(diff + line for line in string.splitlines(True))
    else:
        diff = abs(difference)
        result = ""
        for line in string.splitlines(True):
            if get_indent(line) <= diff:
                result += line.lstrip()
            else:
                result += line[diff:]
        return result


def get_indent(string:str) -> int:
    return len(string) - len(string.lstrip())

def get_indent_multi(string:str) -> int:
    lines = string.splitlines()
    if len(lines) > 1:
        return get_indent(lines[1])
    else:
        return 0

def split_variables_numpy(docstr:str, stripPrivate:bool=False):

    if not docstr.strip():
        return {}, docstr, "", 0

    lines = docstr.splitlines(True)

    header = ""
    for i in range(len(lines)-1):
        if lines[i].strip() == "Parameters" and lines[i+1].strip() == "----------":
            indent = get_indent(lines[i])
            i += 2
            break
        header += lines[i]
    else:
        return {}, docstr, "", get_indent_multi(docstr)

    variables = {}
    while i < len(lines)-1 and lines[i].strip():
        splitted = lines[i].split(maxsplit=1)
        var = splitted[0]
        if len(splitted) > 1:
            varType = splitted[1]
        else:
            varType = " "
        varStr = ""
        i += 1
        while i < len(lines) and get_indent(lines[i]) > indent:
            varStr += lines[i]
            i += 1
        if stripPrivate:
            varStr = strip_private(varStr)
        variables[var] = (varType, varStr)

    footer = ""
    while i < len(lines):
        footer += lines[i]
        i += 1

    if stripPrivate:
        header = strip_private(header)
        footer = strip_private(footer)

    return variables, header, footer, indent
```