# Concatenate sphinx doc from base and derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, documentation, python-sphinx

The accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000179/sphinx-insert-argument-documentation-from-parent-method) provides a handy decorator for inserting the docstring of a base class's method into the documentation of a given derived class's method. This way, when documenting the derived class, the docstring of the base class's method isn't just replaced by the docstring of the derived class's method, but both are concatenated. This is useful for avoiding text duplication when documenting both the base class and the derived ones.

Does sphinx provide the same functionality?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you need in addition to the accepted answer to the linked question?

Comment: Simple to know if sphinx can provide a similar functionality.

Comment: If you are asking if there is any *built-in* functionality, then the answer is no. But Sphinx is extensible so it is very likely possible to create something. Perhaps you can use the solution in the other answer to the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012943/407651.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently using the answer in my main post. We'll see if in the future more functionality is added.